# Why admin page of Django is not showing up database or table

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I wanted Django to show up my table in the admin site of Django.
I did everything fine, I did both makemigration and migrate and also I registered my table in admin.py.
by the way, I use the Postgres database.

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Destination
admin.site.register(Destination)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models    
class Destination(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    desc = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pic')
```

Comment: Add code of your table in `models.py` and `admin.py`, so we could help you to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for your response, you can see my codes of model.py and admin.py.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `DestinationAdmin` class in your `admin.py`

```
class DestinationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = [
    'name',
    'price',
    'desc',
  ]
admin.site.register(Destination)
```

Watch [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/)

Comment: @Hashmat Accept this answer if it was useful.